# Laravel 5.3 -> 5.4 Reflection Exception

Tags: php, laravel-5.4, eloquent

I've upgraded from laravel 5.3 to 5.4. Now I get **Reflection Exception Class eloquent.saving: App\model_name does not exist**.
Everything else looks and works fine. I can query it , retrieve it , display it in a Vue browse - just the saving part is throwing fits. And it happens with every model and their respective controllers.

Example with the simplest model :

Model

```
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Bank extends Model
{
  protected $guarded = ['id'];
}
```

Controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App;
use App\Bank;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class TestController extends Controller
{

  public function test1(Request $request) {

    /** @var \App\Bank $bank */
    // get record
    $bank = Bank::first();
    // change data
    $bank->bic = "xxx";
    // dump it - looks ok
    dump($bank);
    // this throws reflection error
    $bank->save();

  }
}
```

No custom code has been changed. Just the upgrade (and applicable changes from upgrade guide + tinker was added). I've cleared the cache, cleared compiled views , done optimize , dump-autoload ... the works.
This is a mid step to laravel 5.5. But same happens if I upgrade directly to 5.5.
No clue where to start looking.

Update from comments:

Creating a new object throws Carbon exception. Setting $timestamps = false in model gets rid of the Carbon error and I can create new model and save it. However, if I find that same record and try to save it , I get the Reflection Exception again.

Update

If I downgrade back to 5.3 , everything starts working immediately.

Comment: Can you create new or do you get the same error?

Comment: Are your models definitely in the root of the App folder?  `namespace App;`

Comment: @kerrin . Yes, the models are at the correct spot. On the second comment ... we're getting somewhere. I actually didn't try to create one yet. If it try to do new Bank() , i get Carbon error : DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (<?xml version="1.0") at position 0 (<): Unexpected character. However, if I do the same thing in Tinker, it works ... up to save(). Then it fails with reflection exception.

Answer (score 1):

There was an event in EventServiceProvider that listened to "eloquent.saving" - and was totally forgotten. There was a change in how events are handled in 5.4 (via laracast Talinon)